# LockerService is nothing to do with Javascript/Iframe in Salesforce Classic

Tags: locker-service, salesforce-classic

I am asking question just to ensure that my understanding is correct.I have read [Writing Secure code with Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm) and [LockerService and Lightning Container Component:Securely Using third-party Libraries in Lightning Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html).

It mentioned that Locker Service does not effect Salesforce classic which mean I still safe if I using Iframe, Javascript Library or javascript code in Salesforce classic ?Is this understanding correct?

Comment: While you should be, you are not doing yourself or your client if applicable any favors

Comment: Are you thinking to embed lightning components on VF pages to use on Salesforce classic? What's the use-case? Otherwise I would highly recommend to write lightning components respecting locker service for their reusability in classic and LEX.

Comment: We do not  plan to use lightning component.But we got a lot of javascript in visualforce , javascript chart library in visualforce.We are thinking we are not impact by Locker Service, just asking if we think it  correctly before it late.